# Не срабатывает исключение

Tags: java, исключения

Есть некоторый метод для чтения текстового файла

```
public void readTXT(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();

        //тело метода

        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
}
```

есть метод, который вызывает `readTXT()`

```
public void create(String xlsxFileName, String txtFileName) {
    //набор переменных

    try {
        readTXT(txtFileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
    }

    //тело метода
}
```

Передаю в метод `readTXT()` имя несуществующего файла. Метод, как и полагается бросает исключение. Но вот уже метод `create()` по каким-то причинам не ловит это исключение и продолжает выполнятся далее.
Собственно в этом и вопрос - почему не срабатывает catch в методе `create()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`catch` в методе `create` не срабатывает потому, что это исключение уже было перехвачено в `catch` метода `readTXT`. Всё дело в том, что

```
catch(IOException e) { }
```

перехватывает, в том числе и исключение `FileNotFoundException` поскольку оно унаследовано от `IOException`. А перехваченное исключение повторно  не генерируется. Иными словами, если блок `catch` перехватил какое-то исключение, то после него выполнение идёт так, будто исключения и не было. Если это исключение нужно передать дальше, то можно сделать, например, так:

```
catch (IOException e) {
    if (e instanceof FileNotFoundException)
        throw e;
}
```

Можно также воспользоваться тем, что блок `try` может иметь несколько связанных с ним блоков `catch`, обрабатывающие различные типы исключений, а также тем, что проверка исключений происходит "сверху вниз". В этом случае можно сделать так:

```
try {
    // . . .
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Обработка ситуации, когда файл не найден.
    throw e;
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // Обработка остальных ошибок ввода-вывода.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал, что IOException также перехватывает FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 3):

Не ловится потому что вы его уже обработали. Нужно бросать исключение опять

```
public void readTXT(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
    ...
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        if (ioe instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
            throw ioe;
        }
    }
}
```

**Дополнено**

Не очень хороший вариант я привел. Так лучше:

```
public void readTXT(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
    ...
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    ...
    }
}
```